# Create extension in Swift 5 for Dictonary[String:Any]

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create extension for Dictionary [String:Any] which is received from API Response.

Right Now I am doing below way

I have created `func getDataFromJson` this is working fine, Please let me know how to do that.

```
func getDataFromJson(json: AnyObject) -> Data?{
    do {
        print("json = \(json)")
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print("\n\n\nError => getDataFromJson => \(myJSONError)")
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This is my response and I want to "data" to Data

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Country List",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": “ABC”,
            "code": "A",
            "phone_code": "+91”,
            "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": “ZYX”,
            "code": “Z”,
            "phone_code": "+1”,
            "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        }
     ]
}
```

> I want to get data this way `jsonResponse["data"].retriveData()`

Comment: Do you want o get the data to create the objects from the received array ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes I want to create Country Object

Comment: This looks like a completely different question.

Comment: @Vivek check edited answer

Comment: I think you should ask a new question since `data` is an array so this part has nothing to do with your question about writing an extension to `Dictionary`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think I properly raise question regarding extension which is return Data, Any way thank you for your help.

Comment: Well you have answers with such extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that encodes the dictionary, the function throws any error so it can be properly handled. Since `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:` takes an `Any` parameter this function can also be implemented for an array etc

```
extension Dictionary {
    func retriveData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
    }
}
```

Simple example

```
let dict = ["abc": 123, "def": 456]

do {
   let data = try dict.retriveData()
   let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Int].self, from:data)
   print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Another way is to use `Result` if you're on Swift 5 (shortened after comment from vadian)

```
extension Dictionary {
    func retriveData() -> Result<Data, Error> {
        return Result { try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self) }            
    }
}
```

and an example

```
let result = try dict.retriveData()
switch result {
   case .success(let data):
       let dictionary = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Int].self, from:data)
       print(dictionary)
   case .failure(let error):
      print(error) 
}
```

Comment: `, options:.prettyPrinted` is meaningless here

Comment: @Sh_Khan Thanks I'll remove it. Stupid copy/paste error

Comment: Joakim, using the `Result` API you can even write `func retrieveData() -> Result<Data, Error> { return Result { try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)} }`. It handles the `success/failure` cases on your behalf. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/preserving_the_results_of_a_throwing_expression

Answer (score 0):

a copy of your function transposed to an extension can be

```
extension Dictionary {
        func retriveData() -> Data? {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            } catch let myJSONError {
                print("\n\n\nError => getDataFromJson => \(myJSONError)")
            }
            return nil
        }
 }
```

Comment: Should I get from this way `jsonResponse["data"].retriveData()` ?

Comment: I can't get this way right now, I want to get data from my json response which is getting from server and I want to get data from `jsonResponse["data"]`

Comment: this extension works exactly as your function. maybe jsonResponse["data"] is not a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Correct json

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Country List",
    "data": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ABC",
        "code": "A",
        "phone_code": "+91",
        "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ZYX",
        "code": "Z",
        "phone_code": "+1",
        "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Model

```
struct Datum: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, code, phoneCode, flag: String 
}
```

Decoding data only

```
        let str = """
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Country List",
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ABC",
            "code": "A",
            "phone_code": "+91",
            "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ZYX",
            "code": "Z",
            "phone_code": "+1",
            "flag": "country-flags/-shiny.png"
        }
    ]
}

"""

    do {

        let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8)) as! [String:Any]
        let content = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic["data"])
        let dec = JSONDecoder()
        dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let res = try dec.decode([Datum].self, from: content)
        print(res)
    }
    catch {

        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I want to create create `extension `, Not method

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
// Response Dictionary
let jsonResponse : [String:Any] = ["data":["key1":"value1",
                                           "key2":"value2",
                                           "key3":"value3",
                                           "key4":"value4"]]

// check dictionary contains value for key "data"
if let dataDict = jsonResponse["data"] as? [String:Any] {
    // convert dictionary to data
    let jsonData = dataDict.retriveData()
    print("Json Data :- ", jsonData != nil ? "Success" : "Data is nil")
}

// Dictionary exxtension for converting dictionary to json data
extension Dictionary {
    func retriveData() -> Data? {
        do {
            print("json = \(self)")
            return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        } catch let myJSONError {
            print("\n\n\nError => getDataFromJson => \(myJSONError)")
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vivek, please try this one.